# configure codeblocks with plugins

Tags: configuration, installation, codeblocks

I am tryingt o compile code-blocks 16,  from source, but I do not have, (nor want) some of the contributor plug-ins dependencies.

In the configure File, I see some configure options:

```
-with-contrib-plugins=<list>     compile contrib plugins in <list>.
                          plugins may be separated with commas.
                          "all", "yes" or just "--with-contrib-plugins" compiles all contrib plugins
                          "all,-help" or "yes,-help" compiles all contrib plugins except the help plugin
                          "none", "no", "--without-contrib-plugins" or skipping the parameter at all,
                          compiles none of the contrib-plugins
                          Plugin names are: AutoVersioning, BrowseTracker, byogames, Cccc, CppCheck, cbkoders, codesnippets,
                                     codestat, copystrings, Cscope, DoxyBlocks, dragscroll, EditorConfig, EditorTweaks, envvars,
                                     FileManager, headerfixup, help, hexeditor, incsearch, keybinder, libfinder, MouseSap,
                                     NassiShneiderman, ProjectOptionsManipulator, profiler, regex, ReopenEditor, exporter, smartindent, spellchecker,
                                     symtab, ThreadSearch, ToolsPlus, Valgrind, wxcontrib, wxsmith, wxsmithcontrib, wxsmithaui
```

I have tried running configure in a variety of ways, including `./configure --with-contrib-plugins=<list> AutoVersioning, BrowseTracker<list>`

and:

```
./configure -with-contrib-plugins=AutoVersioning, BrowseTracker
```

And also with what sounds like configure all except:

```
./configure --with-contrib-plugins=all -wxsmith -wxsmithcontrib -wxsmithauiconfigure: error: unrecognized option: `-wxsmith'
```

but I keep getting configure errors along the lines of unrecognized option.
Perhaps I am misinterpreting the `-with-contrib-plugins=` option. 
I can run configure with just `./configure` but I would like some of the plug-ins. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Simply Comma separate the packages that you want to install. For instance if you want **only** Valgrind and Doxyblocks, then run configure as follows,

```
./configure --with-contrib-plugins=Valgrind,DoxyBlocks
```

This will install Codeblocks with the plugins Valgrind, DoxyBlocks, etc.

If you want all the plugins simply run configure as

```
./configure --with-contrib-plugins=all
```

Make sure wxWidgets is installed before installing Codeblocks